# Function Transfer of Block Diagram Discrete System

Tags: linear-systems, z-transform, transfer-function

[image: block diagram of a discrete system]

I need to find out the transfer function in Z from this diagram, how can I extract this information from this diagram

Obs: Doing the math, my H_z gave, H_z = 1 + 0.5*z^-1 + 2*z^-2 + 2*z^-3 + 0.5*z^-4 + z^-5, but I don't know if This H_z is correct for this diagram

Comment: This is extremely basic and it's something that comes right outa the textbook.  This really is homework and there is no way to answer it without completely doing it for you.

Comment: Can you show the work you've done so far and where you're stuck?

Comment: @jdip Doing the math, my H_z gave, H_z = 1 + 0.5*z^-1 + 2*z^-2 + 2*z^-3 + 0.5*z^-4 + z^-5, but I don't know if This H_z is correct for this diagram

Comment: Yes, it’s correct

Comment: Ok, thanks!!!!!